# Checking how long iPhone App has been in background when coming into foreground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iPhone App which allows users to log in and interact with a web service. I would like to have the ability for the user to be automatically logged out after a period of inactivity...more specifically if the App has been in the background for over a period of time (for example 1 hour).

I would ideally like to run a check in the App Delegate method applicationWillEnterForeground that checks how long the app has been in the background and then if it has been over the time allowed, take them to the log in screen.

How would I run this check in the above method? I would appreciate some sample code.

If this is not the best way to achieve my requirements then suggestions also welcome!

Many thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    NSDate *thisMagicMoment = [NSDate date];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:thisMagicMoment forKey:@"lastMagicMoment"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSDate *thisMagicMoment = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *lastMagicMoment =  (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastMagicMoment"];

    if (lastMagicMoment==nil)
    {
        NSLog (@"First launch!");
    }
    else
    {
        NSTimeInterval timeOfNoMagic = [thisMagicMoment timeIntervalSinceDate:lastMagicMoment]/3600.0;
        NSLog (@"Application was in background for %.1f hours", timeOfNoMagic);

        //do your stuff - treat NSTimeInterval as double

        if (timeOfNoMagic > 1.0)
        {
            //logout
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (This is personal opinion which you may or may not agree with...) While it's nice of you to do the work for the person posting the question, I think it would be better to post some guidelines for where the person posting the question could go to find more information or things to think about in writing their own implementations. Stack Overflow is gradually getting more questions which end with "please post some code" and that code then shows up in another question with "I've got this code, and now I want to do this extra. Please post the code". Which doesn't really aid learning.

Comment: @Nick: From educational point of view i agree 70%. I think coding has to be learned from studying documentation and also seeing (sometimes copy-pasting) ready made-code. Learning solely from Apple's documentation would be a pain in the... But: SO is not used just for learning - many use it as public repository for short code snippets solving non-crucial problems (encreasing productivity). That said: i gave +1 to your and ade's answer an hour ago exactly because they are educational. I would (if i could) give mine also +1 because it can be a timesaver for anyone with the same 'problem'. :-)

Comment: Can you please let me know if I used applicationDidEnterBackground and
applicationWillEnterForeground method respectively

Comment: The problem with those two methods is that at the time they are called the app is in background (already in background and still in background). It should still work but this is not the kind of job that has to be done in background. See [this chart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17498665/653513).

Answer (score 3):

Save the time when the app enters background to NSUserDefaults. then read it when it re-enters foreground.

In applicationWillEnterForeground if the time difference is over 1 hour you would set a flag or post a notification. i.e. you could have a method in your app delegate that logs the user out, or you could have a check for a flag in viewWillAppear which if necessary logs the user out.

Answer (score 2):

Write the time and date to NSUserDefaults when the application enters the background or is quit. Then read that time and date back from NSUserDefaults in the applicationWillEnterForeground and compare. If it is more than 1 hour (or whatever you set your timeout to be) then display the log in screen.

Answer (score 0):

First set the timer in method applicationdidFinishLaunching:

Now check the time in method applicationDidBecomeActive: this is called every time when user start the app again.

If time is greater than ex(1 hour) then reset timer and logout the user.

Comment: Actually you should stop all running timers when aplication enter background.