# When do the appdelegate methods get called in relation to the view lifecycle methods of your initial view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

What is the sequence of methods that get called when your app loads, especially for these methods:

- applicationDidFinishLaunching
- viewDidLoad
- viewWillAppear
- applicationDidBecomeActive
- awakeFromNib

Answer (score 44):

U could checkout this site http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/ & this flow chart of application.
and check out this flow chart....
[image]

Comment: This is a superb chart, thank you!!!

Comment: What does the URL mean here? I see URL for `DidFinsihLaunchingWithOptions` & `application:OpenURL:SourceApplication:annotation`

Comment: what is the URL mentioned in the figure above?

Comment: @cjahangir  The URL scheme allows developers to launch system apps and third-party apps through URLs. For example, let’s say your app displays a phone number, and you want to make a call whenever a user taps that number. You can use a specific URL scheme to launch the built-in phone app and dial the number automatically. Additionally, you can create a custom URL scheme for your own app so that other applications can launch your app via a URL. So URL scheme you can use to pass parameters to app like filename, phone number, hash, tokens, states…