# iOS Objective-c resuming app while coming from background to foreground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

On iOS objective c platform, I want my application to continue its tasks as it is after entering foreground to background. Initially, when we are working on app foreground, doing some task and then loading the next state by clicking on a button, then meanwhile, for example, some call interrupts in, the app breaks and when call is over, and we again come to foreground, it resumes its previous state before loading rather then the next state. What should i do exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17498665/8196100  -: Try This

Comment: you can use NSOperation Queue for this , and check if there are any pending or running task in queue then resume your task under didEnterForground method.